# svg with object data gets loaded multiple times

Tags: wordpress, svg

I have the following scenario, I am trying to include svg images via object tag.

Here is an example :

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="green-circle.svg" ></object>
```

I need this multiple times on the page, so it's included more than 1 times.
Something like this:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="green-circle.svg" ></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="green-circle.svg" ></object>
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="green-circle.svg" ></object>
```

I thought that the browser will figure out that this is one resource, so loads it 1 time.

But the actual result that it's gets requested multiple times, making my browser unresponsive.

I got a patch working around this.

My question would be: why this is happening? Or is it possible to use object tag without getting into this multiple request issue?

Comment: It rather depends on what HTTP response the server returns when a request for green-circle.svg is made. Does the server say the data is cacheable and for how long it may be cached?

Comment: @RobertLongson Cache-Control:no-cache

Comment: Well that's your problem isn't it?

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks, now I just have to figure out where to change Cache-Control, first wordpress site ever, Thanks